# Is the the base stop function preventing me from parsing my list?

Tags: xml, r

I might be miss using lapply but I'm curious if stop is being used as a function here in the lapply.  I also welcome any suggestions to simplify my code.

```
library(XML)
full_url <- "http://bustracker.muni.org/InfoPoint/XML/stopdepartures.xml"
xml_obj <- xmlParse(full_url)
departure_list <- xmlToList(xml_obj)
lapply(departure_list, function(x) x$stop$departure$edt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`base::stop` is not being called.

It looks like every list entry but the first is named `stop`.  This name will be removed by the subset operation performed by `lapply`, and re-applied to the result.  Thus, `x` as passed to the function does not have an element named `stop`, but it does have an element named `departure`.

I think you want this:

```
lapply(departure_list, function(x) x$departure$edt)
```

The original data looks like this:

```
<departures>
    <generated timezone="-9">2015-08-25 19:38</generated>
    <stop>
        <id>1437</id>
        <name>BAXTER and NORTHERN LIGHTS</name>
        <departure mode="destination">
            <edt>20:10</edt>
            <sdt>20:10</sdt>
            <dev>0</dev>
            <text>1 MULDOON</text>
            <route>
                <id>1</id>
                <name>CROSSTOWN</name>
            </route>
            <dir>I</dir>
        </departure>
        <departure mode="destination">
            <edt>21:10</edt>
            <sdt>21:10</sdt>
            <dev>0</dev>
            <text>1 MULDOON</text>
            <route>
                <id>1</id>
                <name>CROSSTOWN</name>
            </route>
            <dir>I</dir>
        </departure>
...
```